# simplexml echo problem for php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to use an xml to get the title and guid. With the following codo I get nothing returned back to me.

```
$url = 'file.xml';
$obj = simplexml_load_file($url);

$returnTitle = array();
foreach ($obj->title as $title) {
    $returnTitle[];
}

$returnURL = array();
foreach ($obj->guid as $URL) {
    $returnURL[];
}

echo $returnTitle[0]." : ".$returnURL[0]."\n";
echo $returnTitle[1]." : ".$returnURL[1];
```

XML File

```
[item] => Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [title] => here is some title text
        [link] => 
        [comments] => 
        [pubDate] => Fri, 10 Apr 2011 12:00:15 +0000
        [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
            [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
        )     
        [guid] => http://blog.website.com/?p=65421
        [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object()     
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the assignment operation within both for loops

```
foreach ($obj->title as $title) {
    $returnTitle[] = $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you actually assigned something to `$returnTitle` and `$returnURL`...

```
$returnTitle[] = $title;
```

---

Looking at the structure of your XML, I suppose you'd rather need to do something like this:

```
foreach ($obj->item as $item) {
    $returnTitle[] = $item->title;
}
```

Why you want to separate the titles and guids I don't know though, seems to me that they belong together, so you should keep them together:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($obj->item as $item) {
    $items[] = array('title' => $item->title, 'url' => $item->guid);
}

var_dump($items);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "$item[title] : $item[url]\n";
}
```